# Search line for customArrayAdapter - Android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I've been trying to solve this one but couldn't find any answer here.
what i'm trying to do is create an EditText search for custom arrayList, using ArrayAdapter.

All is going well until I actually search for an Object (named Product in this project).
when I search for one, meaning i input chars into the EditText the list goes blank and I cannot see any Items.

This is my code:

```
SearchActivity , receiving the ArrayList from the mainactivity : 

    public class SearchActivity extends Activity {


        EditText editSearch;
        ProductArrayAdapter productsAdapter;
        ListView products;
        static ArrayList<Product> viewList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
            viewList = new ArrayList<Product>(MainActivity.listToBeSent);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), viewList.get(1).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            productsAdapter = new ProductArrayAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.layout_product, viewList);

            products = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listProducts);
            products.setAdapter(productsAdapter);

            editSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchLine);
            editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    String charsToSearch =                  editSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    productsAdapter.filter(charsToSearch);

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    String charsToSearch = editSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    productsAdapter.filter(charsToSearch);

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

ProductArrayAdapter which has the filter() method inside.

```
  public class ProductArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {


        ArrayList<Product> products;

        Context context;
        int resource;




        public ProductArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                 ArrayList<Product> products) {
            super(context, resource, products);
            this.context=context;
            this.resource=resource;
            this.products=products;


        }

        public void filter(String charText) {

            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            this.products.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                this.products.addAll(SearchActivity.viewList);
            } else {
                for (Product singleProduct : SearchActivity.viewList) {
                    if (singleProduct.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(charText)) {
                        products.add(singleProduct);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        static class ViewContainer { 
            public TextView txtName;
            public TextView txtDescription;
            public TextView txtPrice;
            public ImageView imgProduct;
            public ImageView imgOnSale;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewContainer viewContainer;
            View rowView = convertView;

            // means that if it is the first time and we didn't yet inflate the
            // view, so inflate it now. rowView gets the already built or non-exist
            // convertView.
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

                viewContainer = new ViewContainer();
                /*viewContainer.textName = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(this.textViewResource);*/

                viewContainer.txtName = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtName);

                viewContainer.txtDescription = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

                viewContainer.txtPrice = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);

                viewContainer.imgProduct = (ImageView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.productPic);

                viewContainer.imgOnSale = (ImageView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.onSaleImage);




                // adding tag to each rowView , tag can be Object therefore
                // viewContainer = Object.
                rowView.setTag(viewContainer);

            } else {
                viewContainer = (ViewContainer) (rowView.getTag());
            }

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), products.get(1).getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), products.get(2).getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            viewContainer.txtName.setText(products.get(position).getName());
            viewContainer.txtDescription.setText(products.get(position).getDescription());
            viewContainer.txtPrice.setText("Price: " + (products.get(position).getPrice().toString()));
            viewContainer.imgProduct.setImageResource(products.get(position).getImage());
            viewContainer.imgOnSale.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_icon);


            return rowView;

        }
```

I think the main problem is with the viewContainer part.

Appreciate your help !

Thank you Jay, just edited my code, now it does filter some items, but it seems like it doesn't 
filter by the right chars, for example , when I search the letter 'r' it does get 'r' as the charSequence but it shows only the first item , and not the correct one .

here are the edited relevant lines :

on the textChangeListener I entered :

```
@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String charsToSearch = editSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                productsAdapter.getFilter().filter(charsToSearch);

            }
```

and on the ProductArrayAdapter I changed the getView() method to :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewContainer viewContainer;
        //View rowView = convertView;

        // means that if it is the first time and we didn't yet inflate the
        // view, so inflate it now. rowView gets the already built or non-exist
        // convertView.
        if (convertView == null) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            viewContainer = new ViewContainer();

            viewContainer.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtName);

            viewContainer.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

            viewContainer.txtPrice = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);

            viewContainer.imgProduct = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.productPic);

            viewContainer.imgOnSale = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.onSaleImage);




            // adding tag to each rowView , tag can be Object therefore
            // viewContainer = Object.
            convertView.setTag(viewContainer);

        } else {
            viewContainer = (ViewContainer) (convertView.getTag());
        }

        viewContainer.txtName.setText(products.get(position).getName());
        viewContainer.txtDescription.setText(products.get(position).getDescription());
        viewContainer.txtPrice.setText("Price: " + (products.get(position).getPrice().toString()));
        viewContainer.imgProduct.setImageResource(products.get(position).getImage());
        viewContainer.imgOnSale.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_icon);


        return convertView;

    }
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `filter` method. That is not the correct way to handle filtering with an adapter. The `ArrayAdapter` already supports a basic filtering mechanism. Simply do:

```
productsAdapter.getFilter.filter(charsToSearch);
```

For each product stored in the adapter, it'll do a:

```
singleProduct.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(charsToSearch);
```

If the `startsWith()` logic works for you, a quick working solution would be to override the `toString()` method for your `Product` class and have it return `getName()`.  Otherwise, there are really only two solutions available if you want a more custom solution for the filtering logic:

1. Write your own adapter from scratch using `BaseAdapter` and have it implement the `Filterable` interface.  While a very basic implementation isn't too bad, it can be quite daunting if you never did it before.
2. Utilize an existing [3rd party library](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) which allows you to add your own filtering logic.

Also note, when working with the `ArrayAdapter` it's very dangerous to keep your own copy of the list outside of what's constructed with the super.  Especially when filtering is concerned. There's no guarantee that the list used to construct the adapter is the same one you are referencing externally. For further reading, [go here](http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/constructor-woes-androids-arrayadapter/).

For your `getView()` method, make sure you use `getItem(position)` instead of directly referencing `products`. Placing `Toasts` inside there is also not a good idea. When displaying your list, you will end up seeing a ton of `Toasts` pop up all at once.  If you need debuging statements, use `Log` instead. Also, you need to adjust the following lines:

```
rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
viewContainer = new ViewContainer();
```

To this instead:

```
viewContainer = inflater.inflate(resouce, parent, false);
```

You don't need that `rowView` variable at all. Just remove completely from the method and replace with `viewContainer`. Otherwise, your `getView()` method looks fine.

Comment: Thanks Jay , brought me a step closer to a solution! I edited my question with the few changes in the code and with the new problem.

Comment: Do different letters yield different results?  Are you modifying the adapter in any way? What is the `Product` toString() method returning?